# Why can't my Windows 10 machines (and only those machines) connect to the 2.4Ghz band of our wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-router

Strange problem. We got a new router last week, one that throws off two networks. A 2.4Ghz network and a 5Ghz network. Both of our Windows 10 machines have problems connecting to the 2.4Ghz network. It shows a successful connection but with a yellow "warning" triangle. Hovering over the signal strength shows 'Identifying... No Internet Access'.

Neither Windows 10 machine had any problem connecting to the old router with it's sole 2.4Ghz band. And none of our Android phones, iPhones, or Macbooks have problems connecting to the current 2.4Ghz band.

No driver or network adapter change has happened at any point in the last year.

Comment: My guess you dot have a 2.4ghz adapter

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use the 5 GHz band? It works better than 2.4 GHz.

Comment: generally speaking, that yellow icon is supposed to mean that the router is not correctly configured. Windows attempts to periodically download a file from a webserver, and if it can't it displays the "no internet access" message. are other clients able to connect to the 2.4GHz network and access internet? does the 5GHz work for internet?

Comment: Guys, most of the stuff you're asking was covered in the question. @Ramhound I clearly have a dual band adapter as I said the computers worked before on the old router's 2.4 band. Frank Thomas Yes, macbooks and cell phones can use the 2.4 band fine. Only the two Windows 10 desktops have problems getting internet on the 2.4.

Comment: @AaronFranke The upstairs computer, one room away from the router can use the 5GHz fine. The downstairs comp constantly drops the 5. Besides generally wanting things to work, it actually affects the performance of the downstairs computer.